# Calling basic authentication java webservice with C# Client

Tags: c#, java, web-services, client, basic-authentication

I have a c# client application calling java web services. Everything works great but now i need to send some authentication data since we are trying to restrict who calls the web service. The java web service expects basic authentication.

How do i go about providing this in my c# client? I am not using WCF or WSE, just plain webservice (using Add Web Reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a link for the solution i found in case some one needs it. I was able to fix my issue by modifying some of the stuff in the suggested article.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/pchandraker/1052/